# Update multiple rows VS single row + more frequently

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm working on geo visitor tracking script based on campaigns.

Which one is faster & resource friendly?

1. Updating 250 different records every second.

   `update table set views=views+1 where country='US' and campaign='1'`
2. Updating 1 record 250 times every second.

   `update table set data='US:11243;UK:2223...(200 more country)' where campaign='1'`

There are no more than 50 campaigns in the table.

Edit: There is **no difference** between number of queries in both options. country, campaign fields are indexed.

Comment: Less queries = better performance. Generally speaking. Just make sure your tables are properly indexed.

Comment: There is no difference between number of queries in both options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either way you are running 250 `UPDATE` statements a second.

The first way you are only affecting 1/250th of your data, your data is normalised and aggregate queries, e.g. get the global view count for a view, are simple. Also you can filter queries by country and view count easily.

The second way is a mess.. don't even think about it.

Comment: I thought so. Thank you! Any suggestions regarding the table design?

Comment: A `campaign_country_view_count(id, campaign_id, country_id, view_count)` table should do the trick.. you could even have a `campaign_country_view (id, campaign_id, country_id, time)` with one row per view if you want the extra data.

Comment: One more question, how much performance differece would there be between using country codes and IDs that corresponds to countries, for storing & querying?

Comment: @user3841653 both would be almost identical I believe.. that's up to your preference and any framework you are using (some prefer a numeric id).